# android delete file after Images.Media.insertImage

Tags: android

i want to share a bitmap image using intent , so i create file of this image in directory , but i want remove this file created by "Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b,"title", null);"
 after sharing it but i can't  ,here is the code

```
             Picture picture = objetview.capturePicture();

            Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(),
                    picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas c = new Canvas( b );

            picture.draw( c );
            //b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, null);
            String pathofBmp = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b,"title", null);
            Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);
            final Intent emailIntent1 = new Intent(     android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
            emailIntent1.setType("image/png");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent1, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: does anyone know how to do this  ?

Comment: I am still fixing this.. kindly post answer once u r done with it

Comment: Did anybody find an answer to this? Please post if you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getContentResolver().delete(bmpUri, null, null);
```

Hope it works!